# Trigger.io app rejected from app store "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, trigger.io

I'm trying to submit my trigger.io app to the app store and I always receive an email from apple saying that my was is rejected because of "Missing Push Notification Entitlement".

I've searched this issues and followed the common fixes like recreating the provisionning profile but on every submission I always get the rejected email from Apple.

The problem is that my app do *not* use push notification and I don't understand why apple sees my app as using push notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is triggered because Trigger.io core code includes calls to push notification API's as it needs to use the same core library to support both push and non-push apps.

If you read the email from Apple carefully you'll notice that it's just a warning, not an error and you can safely ignore it:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "io.trigger.repro". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
>   correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement.